# How to invoke a method inside a self-invoking function in JavaScript? kinda like Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm recently learning JavaScript and jQuery, but I got this, jQuery has a bunch of methods which can be called through "$.function(arg)/jQuery.function(arg)"... so.. I wanted to make something similar just for the sake of learning and here's my test code...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function (){
        function hello_world(){
            document.write("Hello planet!");
        }
    })();
</script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    /*  HOW DO I CALL "HELLO WORLD IN HERE?"  */
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put it outside the self invoking function x-D

Comment: I mean, would you be able to see an object if you put it inside an opaque box? :-)

Comment: jQuery does assign to a global variable (or actually two: `jQuery` and `$`) so that you can access them. You are just creating a local function - not visible from outside. Omit the IEFE if you don't need it.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the IIFE to a variable, but you must return the `hello_world` function from the IIFE:

```
var hello_world = (function () {
    return function hello_world(){
        console.log("Hello planet!");
    }
})();

hello_world(); // Hello planet!
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dghen3au/)

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery` actually attaches the `jQuery` object to the global `window` object.
That way it can be reached anywhere.

Example with your code:

```
(function (){
    window.hello_world = function(){
        document.write("Hello planet!");
    }
})();

hello_world();
```

I would not recommend using this approach for all your functions though. I'd recommend to have as few global variables/functions as possible, always!

Comment: Yeah, and if you're afraid to pollute the global space, you can minimize the problem by storing everything into an object: `window.mystuffs = {}; window.mystuffs.helloWorld = function () { /* ... */ };`

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for, now I got a question, why does jQuery use this approach instead of simply declaring functions in a .js file?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I would think they do it to create a context where everything is `private` from the user and then expose only the jQuery object to the user. This can be done in other ways too, but I guess the jQuery devs found that way the best for them. :)

Comment: Noticed that this answer was unaccepted, may I ask why? Did you just notice it was wrong, two years later?